# How to do a full clone of a VM?

Tags: virtualization, clone

Environment:

- Host machine: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- Guest machine: Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
- Virtualization system: VirtualBox last version.

How can I perform a **full** clone of my VM ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Selecting the full clone option](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#clone) really does make a full clone of the VM. (If you're having specific problems with that, I recommend editing your question with more details.)

After cloning the VM, if you want both virtual machines to access the same network at the same time, you'll probably want to change the MAC address on the virtual network adapter of one of the VMs.

Further reading:

- [Are there any "traps" in cloning a VirtualBox VM for concurrent use on the same Host/LAN?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14542/are-there-any-traps-in-cloning-a-virtualbox-vm-for-concurrent-use-on-the-same)
- [How do I fix broken networking in cloned virtual machines?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/82322/how-do-i-fix-broken-networking-in-cloned-virtual-machines)

Answer (score 2):

Click on the sheep icon to clone your VM (including snapshots). The sheep is in reference to Dolly the Sheep.

Alternatively, you can export the entire VM into an OVA file which can then be imported into any other VirtualBox (or even VMWare) installation.